# How to call a function of one module in another module

Tags: 7, hooks, ubercart

How can I call a function of one module in another module? I want to call `uc_stock_adjust()` function of uc_stock.module in my own custom module. Is it possible?

Here is my code so far:

```
function my_module_node_presave($node){ 
  if($node->type == 'add_stock') { 
    $stock_value = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value']; 
    $sku = $node->field_sku['und'][0]['value']; 
    if (module_exists('uc_stock') && function_exists('uc_stock_adjust')) {
      uc_stock_adjust($sku, $stock_value); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I want to add and delete stock of products by using reference `uc_stock_adjust()`, which is defined in uc_stock.module, in my custom module. But when I try the above code, it doesn't work.

It giving an error, and the error is:

> Notice: Undefined variable: sku in my_module_node_presave() (line 29 of \sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module)‌​

Comment: have you tried calling the function in your custom module? You can call the functions from any module.

Comment: It is possible by a simple function call (as in PHP), but it isn't recommended. As the most module functions ([hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7)) are called on a certain event automatically by Drupal.

Comment: iam calling uc_stock_adjust function of uc_stock module in my custom module under node_presave function. But it giving an error, and the error is:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sku in my_module_node_presave() (line 29 of D:\xampp\htdocs\photo\photogallary\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module).

Comment: any solution for the above error: undefinrd variable?

Comment: Please add more information to the question and it can be reviewed for re-opening. At the moment the only sense this could possibly make is that you want to know how to call a PHP function, which of course is off topic for this site. Just so you're aware, we've had a [recent discussion](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2287) about poor quality questions and the refusal of new users to read the FAQ and conform their questions to it. The community have indicated that they would like such questions closed, which is what I'm doing.

Comment: i want to add and delete stock of products by using reference of uc_stock module of ubercart module in my custom module

Comment: function my_module_node_presave($node){
    
  if($node->type == 'add_stock') {
    $stock_value = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value'];
 
 $sku = $node->field_sku['und'][0]['value'];
 
 if (module_exists('uc_stock') && function_exists('uc_stock_adjust')) {
    
 
 uc_stock_adjust($sku, $stock_value);
    
 }
  }
 
 
}
so far this is my code

Comment: actually im trying to call uc_stock_adjust() in my custom module to add or delete stock of products. But the code is not working. Help

Comment: Editing your question rather than leaving new info as comments, and inserting your code into your question with proper formatting, would be helpful. If you clarify and expand your question adequately, it could be reopened and you could get better help.

Comment: I have edited your question with info that you provided to make it better. If you also edit it and add info like, what steps do you do to "try" the code, and what happens when it "doesn't work", that would help too. And you should also look at [module_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) if you haven't already. And tell us what version you're using.

Comment: beth im using version 7.

Answer (score 15):

To call the function of one module in another module:

1. If the function is not in the .module file, call [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7)

   ```
   //Load node.admin.inc from the node module
   module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
   ```
2. Call the function from the other module

   ```
   function_you_want_to_call();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined variable: sku` means that you have not declared a value for the variable `$sku`. Have you done debugging to make sure that `$node->field_sku['und'][0]['value']` outputs a value?

Comment: yes i had done debugging and it outputs the sku value that i have entered manually and that is: tshirts

Answer (score 0):

See [module_invoke()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7). This calls a function (hook) in a specified module.

The given hook `uc_stock_adjust()` can thus be called by: `module_invoke('uc_stock', 'adjust');`. (Note that this is because the function follows Drupal conventions of module_name_function_name).

If desired additional arguments can also be passed to a function's parameters with: `module_invoke('uc_stock', 'adjust', $first_param_to_pass, $second_param_to_pass, $etc);`